# Handling keyboard input in QListView

Tags: qt, events, user-interface, listview, signals

I would like to delete an item from a QListView when the delete key is pressed. I know I can override QListView::keyPressEvent but I need to do the deletion from a different class. Is there any signal I could use to detect the delete key?

Comment: What do you mean by _from a different class_?

Comment: I have a QWidget which contains two QListView. In my model, the data is pushed to the list views by the widget, so they don't know where to access the data from, how to delete it, etc. That's why I need the QWidget to handle all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [QObject::installEventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter), I think it is exactly what you are looking for and also has a small example for your case.